# mod rewrite variable is always index.php

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

I want to rewrite `domain.com/pagename` to `/index.php?page=$pagename` with this simple rule:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?page=$1 [L]
```

But paradoxically I always get `index.php` for `$1` and not `pagename`, why is that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have an infinite redirect loop, that's why you get an unexpected result (weird you don't get an Internal Server Error, by the way...)

Here is a rule for what you want

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)$ /index.php?page=$1 [L]
```

It checks if the url is not a physical folder/file before rewriting it internally. This rule is valid for one-level url only (eg. `http://example.com/placeholder` and not `http://example.com/placeholder/somethingelse`)

Answer (score 1):

Try this

http://example.com/pagename => http://example.com/index.php?page=$pagename

```
RewriteRule ^pagename$ /index.php?page=$pagename&%{QUERY_STRING}
```

Comment: thanks for answer, but actually I do not want to just match "pagename" its just a placeholder, it could also be anything else like "start", "contact" etc.

Comment: But "_I want to rewrite domain.com/pagename to /index.php?page=$pagename_"